# Only view uername

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, usernametoken

I want to view this code only with USERNAME, however the public display name taking over. how to only display USERNAME?

```
function display_current_user_display_name () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $display_name = $user->user_login;
    return $user->display_name;
}
add_shortcode('current_user_display_name', 'display_current_user_display_name');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning `$user->display_name;`. You need to return `$display_name`. Try the below code.

```
function display_current_user_display_name () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $display_name = $user->user_login;
    return $display_name;
}
add_shortcode('current_user_display_name', 'display_current_user_display_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter code:

```
function display_current_user_display_name () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return $user->user_login;
}
add_shortcode('current_user_display_name', 'display_current_user_display_name');
```

Comment: Please elaborate how/why this is better code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).